# angular not displaying object inside array of object

Tags: angular

i'm using angular to get data from an api.. the data structure i have is array(object).array(object)

- this is my data

[image]

- and this is the component ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

collaborator:Collaborator[]=[];
entreprise:Entreprise[]=[];


  constructor(private serv:EntrepriseService) { }

 getcoll(){
  this.serv.getcollaboratorses().subscribe(res =>{
     this.collaborator = res.content;
     // this.entreprise=res.content.entreprise;
      console.log(res);
    },err =>{

      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

- the collaborator module

```
import {Entreprise} from './entreprise';
export interface Collaborator {

    id:String;
    name:String;
    email:String;
    password:String;
    phone:String;
    entreprise:Entreprise[];
    roles:any[];
}
```

- entreprise module

```
export interface Entreprise {

    id:String;
    name:String;
    socialPurpose: String;
    businessCode:String;
    activityDomain:String;
    email:String;
    password:String;
    logo:String;
    roles:any[];

}
```

- html code

```
<p *ngFor="let ee of collaborator">
   {{ee.name}} - <ng-container *ngIf="ee?.entreprise"> {{ee.entreprise.name}} </ng-container>

  </p>
```

when i delete this part `<ng-container *ngIf="ee?.entreprise"> {{ee.entreprise.name}} </ng-container>` the code works fine and i can the browser dislays all the collaborators'name but when i try to display their roles or entreprise i cannot ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ee.entreprise is an array, name doesn't exists there.
warp it with another ngfor like in the code below

```
<p *ngFor="let colab of collaborator">
   {{colab.name}} - 
    <ng-container *ngIf="colab.entreprise?.length"> 
        <span *ngFor="let ee of colab.entreprise"> 
            {{ee.name}} 
        </span>
    </ng-container>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ee.enterprise` is an array, the `ee.enterprise.name` does not exist. 
First it has to be indexed. For example "`ee.enterprise[0].name`, `ee.enterprise[1].name` and so on.

Most probably an other `ngFor` will be needed for the array of `ee.enterprise`.

Comment: i treid  ` <p *ngFor="let ee of collaborator">
   {{ee.name}} - <div *ngFor="let ent of ee.entreprise" > {{ent.name}} </div>
 
  </p>` but not working too